# jsp- Unable to call javascript function in Onclick attribute

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a simple javascript function written in the body tag:

```
 <script >
        function update(param){
            var ut = document.getElementById("usertype"+param);
            alert(ut);
        };


    </script>
```

I want to call this function in my onclick button which looks something like below:

```
 <%
        try {


            String str = "<table border=2><tr><th>Username</th><th>New Username</th><th>User Type</th><th>Update</th></tr>";
              int rowid = 0;
            while (rs.next()) {
                String autype = rs.getString("ausertype");
                str += "<tr><td>" + rs.getString("ausername") + "</td> <td><input type=\"text\" name=\"NewUserName\" " +
                        "value=\"\"></td> <td>";

                if (autype.equalsIgnoreCase("Superuser")) {
                    str += "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"usertype"+rowid+"\"  value=\"Superuser\" checked> Superuser ";
                }else{
                    str += "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"usertype"+rowid+"\" value=\"Superuser\" > Superuser ";
                }
                if(autype.equalsIgnoreCase("Basic")) {
                    str += " <input type=\"radio\" name=\"usertype"+rowid+"\" value=\"Basic\"  checked > Basic ";
                }else {
                    str += " <input type=\"radio\" name=\"usertype"+rowid+"\" value=\"Basic\"   > Basic ";
                }
                if(autype.equalsIgnoreCase("View")){
                    str += " <input type=\"radio\" name=\"usertype"+rowid+"\" value=\"View\"  checked> View ";
                }else {
                    str += " <input type=\"radio\" name=\"usertype"+rowid+"\" value=\"View\"  > View ";
                }
                str += "</td><td><button type=\"button\" onclick="+update(rowid)+">Update User</button></td> </tr>";
            rowid ++;

            }

%>
```

As shown above, I was unable to resolve the method `update` in the onclick button as it is enclosed in a Java tag `<% %>`.When I removed the tag,it can resolve the javascript function. I need to have the java tag enclosed for my code.

Is there any workaround for this issue?

Comment: `str += "</td><td><button type=\"button\" onclick=\"update(" + rowid + ")\">Update User</button></td> </tr>";` (i.e. wrong enclosing quotes)

Comment: When do you want to call the `update` method? When the user clicks the button? Is there any error in the browser console?

Comment: When I click on a button, it will fire the function and shows the rowid. Right now, it works but I am not too sure how do I make the function update a table in mysql with it's rowid .

Comment: You have to fire an AJAX call from the function, and have a servlet on the server side to handle it. You can get some inspiration e.g. from https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/09/jquery-ajax-servlets-integration-building-a-complete-application.html

Comment: I see. Because I am able to get rowID and there's hundreds of the same button on each row. So if I hit update button on user1, it should update that user's info in database and so on and so forth

Comment: In your tutorial it involves many files, I am just planning to do everything inside the same jsp file for simplicity.

Comment: _I am just planning to do everything inside the same jsp file for simplicity_ - well, not that it was impossible to do that within a single JSP, but it definitely wouldn't be something I would call a simple solution; sometimes is easier to split the stuff into separate files - [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) principle

Comment: The reason I don't opt for separation is because this is a temporary jsp created just for a short period of time.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing it below way :

```
str += "</td><td><button type=\"button\" onclick='update('+rowid+')'>Update User</button></td> </tr>";
```

Comment: How do I update the sql table in javascript function if this works?

Comment: you cann't update it using javascript. Use Ajax call through javascript(send rowid in ajax data) and then in your ajax php file, write your query

Comment: I don't have a php file, is it possible to do everything in jsp?

Comment: yes.you can use another jsp to get result of ajax call.